# Reading Server-Sent Events using reactive Spring WebClient and feeding them to a slow/restricted consumer produces an OverflowException

Tags: java, project-reactor, server-sent-events, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I have the following test:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.codec.ServerSentEvent;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

class MainTest {
    private TestServer server;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() throws Exception {
        server = new TestServer();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void cleanup() throws Exception {
        server.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        WebClient client = WebClient.builder().build();

        client.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:9999/")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>>() {
                })
                .map(ServerSentEvent::data)
                .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
                .blockLast();
    }

    private static class TestServer {
        private final Server server;

        private TestServer() throws Exception {
            server = new Server(9999);
            server.setHandler(new AbstractHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handle(String target, Request request, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    PrintWriter writer = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                        writer.println("id:" + i);
                        writer.println("data:" + i);
                        writer.println();
                    }

                    request.setHandled(true);
                }
            });
            server.start();
        }

        void shutdown() throws Exception {
            server.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

It starts a server that emits one million SSE (server-sent event) messages, and tries to read them all using Spring's reactive `WebClient`. The only non-trivial thing is that before consuming the messages, I inserted `.publishOn(Schedulers.single())` as it is recommended for slow consumers (and in my real project I actually have a relatively slow consumer, namely `KafkaSender`, that already uses `Schedulers.single()` by default).

The corresponding snippet of the POM follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.31.v20200723</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

On my machine, this test fails immediately:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests

    at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithOverflow(Exceptions.java:231)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET http://localhost:9999/ [DefaultClientResponse]
Stack trace:
        at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithOverflow(Exceptions.java:231)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.emit(FluxBufferPredicate.java:304)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.onNextNewBuffer(FluxBufferPredicate.java:260)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.tryOnNext(FluxBufferPredicate.java:214)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.onNext(FluxBufferPredicate.java:186)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:845)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.emit(FluxBufferPredicate.java:300)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.onNextNewBuffer(FluxBufferPredicate.java:260)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.tryOnNext(FluxBufferPredicate.java:214)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.onNext(FluxBufferPredicate.java:186)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drainAsync(FluxFlattenIterable.java:405)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FluxFlattenIterable.java:649)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFlattenIterable.java:249)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:218)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:351)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:348)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:588)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:90)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:316)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:303)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:417)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:271)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:355)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockLast(Flux.java:2482)
        at MainTest.test(MainTest.java:42)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
        at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
        at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:128)
```

If I remove the `publishOn(...)` line, it works fine.

On the one hand, I understand that a fast producer can overwhelm a slow/restricted consumer. On the other hand, I'm using a reactive flow, so I expect that the web client does not read anything if there is no demand.

Is it that I do something wrong here? Or it is an erroneous behavior (by the libraries)?

If I'm doing something wrong, how can this be fixed? `.onBackpressureBuffer()` just before the `.publishOn(...)` seems to allow the program run without errors, but is it a correct solution? What if it runs out of memory? Is there any way to just read slower?

The full project code is here: https://github.com/rpuch/webclient-sse-with-slow-consumer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I change `reactor-core` version from `3.3.2` to `3.3.3`, the test passes: it heats the processor for about 2 minutes (well, a million messages, you know), but it finishes successfully.

So it looks like the issue was caused by a bug in `reactor-core`, probably this one https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1937 (closed in `3.3.3`).

Answer (score 2):

You are right about `.onBackpressureBuffer()`, it can handle the situation, but also at the same time you have the problem with the memory.

By default Spring WebFlux/WebClient relies on the TCP back pressure. If you need Reactive Streams semantics across network boundary you can try [RSocket](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#rsocket) and its integration with Spring Framework.

Comment: Thank you Violeta. I'll look at RSocket.